# Voltage drops to 3V when connecting USB to 5V Source

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am trying to build a solar phone charger. I have a 18V solar panel and I connected the output to a diode and a voltage regulator. The voltage regulator drops the voltage from 18V to 5V and I can read that on the multimeter during daylight. Once I connect the phone, I can see that the voltage at the inlet of the phone drops from 5V to 3V. The phone shows that it is charging, but actually it is discharging.

I assume that the 5V - 3V drop is due to the internal resistance of the phone and here is one of the questions. Do I need to have a voltage regulator that gives a higher voltage output of 7V, for example? This would mean that with the phone resistance, the inlet voltage will end out being around 5V.

And the second question is why is my phone discharging instead of charging, considering that I have a diode right before the voltage regulator?

Comment: Measure the voltage coming out of your solar panel when you have your phone connected to the regulator. Make sure that voltage is still in the regulator's input range. Then you'll know if Dirk's answer is correct.

Comment: 19.35 V panel -> 5.11 V regulator (No phone) || 6.87V panel -> 4.4 V regulator (With phone). Does this confirm Dirk's statement?

Comment: Depends on your regulator, but almost certainly yes.

Comment: @Physther Please put that information in your question. Use the edit function.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a bigger solar panel or more light, and the voltage is dropping because not enough current is being supplied. Also, if the regulator is linear you are throwing away most of the power of the solar panel when dropping the voltage to 5V

You need the diode after the regulator

Comment: I don't like your answer... You told me the thing I was worried about. That the solar panel is not good enough for this. So you think having a 7V voltage regulator would be a bad idea? As for the diode, I think you are right. I will change it now.

Comment: @Physther This is not perfect, but should give you an idea http://www.electroschematics.com/4746/solar-charger-circuit/